# Prove that any integer can written as differences of two numbers with same prime divisors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that any integer can written as differences of two numbers with same prime divisors.

The problem seems wrong since we can prove that it is impossible for $1$ and any prime bigger than $2$.I need the original problem but not an answer since I want to think on it.Maybe we should prove it for any composite number.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I am sure about the part two numbers with same prime divisors.

Comment: Odd numbers *cannot* be written as the difference of two numbers with same prime divisors since $\text{odd}=\text{even}-\text{odd}$ or $\text{odd}=\text{odd}-\text{even}$. Even numbers *can* be written as the difference of two numbers with same prime divisors since $2m=4m-2m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement cannot hold for all composite numbers. A simple example is $n=9$. Actually, $n$ is a difference of two numbers with same prime divisors if and only if $n$ is even - see mathlove's argument above.